# I've attempted a case when statement

Tags: oracle

I have attempted to use

```
case 
   when cc.create_date_time < 04/17/2019 ' 
      then 'counted'
   when cc.create_date_time > 04/17/2019  
      then 'need counted'
   else null
end as TIME_GAP
```

with no luck - whatever is on the first line as in the 'counted' returns for all data even though there are results done before that date that should say need counted... how do I fix this...?

If something was counted 04/17/2019 and later its good if it has been counted before that date then I need it to tell me that... thanks

Comment: Please include the actual code you are using.  What you pasted above won't even compile, I think.

Comment: --,case when EXPTD_QTY <> ACTL_INVN_QTY then EXPTD_QTY-ACTL_INVN_QTY else null end as variance1
--,decode (cc.stat_code, '0', 'Unprocessed', '90', 'Processed', '99', 'Expired') as Status
,dsp_locn, case_nbr,cc.user_id, cc.create_date_time
--,case when cc.create_date_time > 04/07/2019 then 'counted' else 'Need Counted' end as count_status
,case when cc.create_date_time  < 04/17/2019 ('MM/DD/YYYY') then 'counted'

Comment: when cc.create_date_time > 04/17/2019 ('MM/DD/YYYY') then 'need counted'
       else null
     end as TIME_GAP
from WH_GHC1.CYCLE_COUNT_HIST cc inner join item_master im on im.sku_id = cc.sku_id
inner join locn_hdr lh on lh.locn_id = cc.locn_id
where cc.whse = 'PH3'
--and cc.stat_code = 0
--and dsp_sku = '&SKU'
and cc.create_date_time > '&StartDate'
and (
------------
--   ="(im.dsp_sku ='"&C2&"' and batch_nbr = '"&E2&"') or"

------------



------------
)
--order by cc.create_date_time

--stat_code: 0 is unprocessed, 90 is processed, 99 is expired,

Comment: it wouldn't let me paste it as one... appoligies

Comment: select dsp_sku, batch_nbr      <<---- that should be in from of the case when statement @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include clarifications or further information. In particular code is hard to read in comments because of the poor layout and formatting.

Comment: You need to put the string which represent dates into **single quotes** - like this: `when cc.create_date_time < '04/17/2019'`

Answer (score 0):

If `CREATE_DATE_TIME` column's datatype is `DATE` (it should be), why are you comparing it to strings? `'04/17/2019'` is a string. Either use `DATE` literal, or convert that string to date with the `TO_DATE` function and appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
case when cc.create_date_time < date '2019-04-17' then ...
```

or

```
case when cc.create_date_time < to_date('04/17/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') then ...
```

Comment: doesn't work... it makes all the data return the value even though there are dates before 04/17/2019 @littlefoot

Comment: Please, post CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data statements so that we could see what you really have.

Comment: I got it should be as follows for my situation                                          ,case when trunc(cc.create_date_time) <= to_date('04/17/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') then 'counted' else 'not counted' end as countstat

Comment: OK; TRUNC it is, to remove time component. Thank you for letting us know.